# How do dapps connect to blockchain network?

Tags: metamask, dapps

Once the simple blockchain web applications runs on the web browser it uses the `metamask` to connect to the blockchain network, when it comes to mobile applications how the application connects to blockchain network ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some clarifications:

1. The dApp or Blockchain web application does not use MetaMask to connect to the Blockchain. A dApp on the Ethereum blockchain requires something called a `provider` that will help them connect with an ethereum node. Once the provider builds the bridge between the application and the node- we say that it is now connected to the blockchain.
2. The users require an address to exist and issue transactions on the dApp platform. Metamask is a wallet, that contains your ethereum address and private key that you use to sign and authorize transactions.

If you build a mobile application and create connection with a provider to an ethereum node, you will have that application interacting on the blockchain. But as a user, you will require some kind of a wallet that will help you transact on the platform or do any kind of activity.